# A Small XML Modifier

Tags: javascript, xml, html

My company is partnered with another company that provides us various flash gauges that we use and integrate with our software.  These gauges use XML files for configuration, that aren't terribly large, but not intuitive to someone who doesn't know exactly what they're looking at.  I've taken it on myself to develop something small that I can provide our customers and employees that configure this software that would utilize some form of GUI interface, however simple, that can be used to modify these XML files and then save them, client side.  The idea is that this could be slipped into the package that is installed on-site, opened locally, and used.

We currently have a local html page that shows all the gauges functioning and is stored in the install package so that customers can pick which gauges they want to use.  This led me initially to look into just extending this html page to provide the functionality I'm looking for.  Through various research on the XML/HTML DOM and some JavaScript, I've realized that while I could do the manipulations I wish to do, there isn't a way to get this modified XML doc to the client's machine without installing another piece of software, such as PHP.

What I'm looking for is either someone to inform me that I'm way off base and that there is a clean way of using HTML/JavaScript/XML to do what I'm trying to do (I know this is most likely a pipe dream, but still desirable), or guidance on what language this would be implementable in with a small size footprint.  The current package we install is only about 26mb for reference.  I don't mind doing further research, this is really just a starting/planning step for feasibility's sake.  So the hope is that I don't have to install any new software on the client machine, and this can be implemented on a local machine with no server-side interaction for minimal space.

Thanks all in advance for feedback.  It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that could help you for manipulating XML, you could just save the output in another XML file.
Just make a layout with html/php/css/Javascript.

```
        var req = new Request({
    method : 'get',
    url: 'templates/absolu/animation.xml',
    onSuccess: function(txt,xml){
      /* we grab the XML data, particularly the content of diapositive tags */

      x=xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("diapositive");
      for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("image");
        {
          try{listeImages[i] = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}
          catch (er){listeImages[i] = '';
                     list[i]['Image'] = xxx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}
        }
        xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("url");
        {
          try{listeURL[i] = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}
          catch (er){listeURL[i] = '';
                     list[i]['URL'] = xxx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}
        }
        xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("text");
        {
          try{listeTextes[i] = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
              liste[i]['Texte'] = xxx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}
          catch (er){listTextes[i] = '';}
        }
        xxx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("date");
        {
        try{listeDates[i] = xxx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}
          catch (er){listeDates[i] = "21112035";}
        }
      }
```

Here is the content of my XML file (snippet)

```
  <diaporama>
      <diapositive>
      <date>01012015</date>
      <image>images/promos/promo-1.jpg</image>
      <url><![CDATA[index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=70&Itemid=66&promo=FR2&promoname=Avantages_du_cable_30_95]]></url>
  </diapositive>  

  <diapositive>
    <date>01012015</date>
    <image>images/promos/promo-2.jpg</image>
    <url><![CDATA[index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=70&Itemid=66&promo=FR2&promoname=Avantages_du_cable_30_95]]></url>
  </diapositive>
</diaporama>
```

Hope it'll help you a little bit!
Have a nice day!

Comment: Yea, I know how to traverse through the XML file and get the data I need.  My problem, is that I don't know how to save the output to another XML file.  Seemingly you know how to do this.  I'd be most appreciative for a bit of help in this area.  I noticed you mentioned PHP.  I'm trying to avoid using PHP as I don't want to have to install any additional software to achieve this if at all possible.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this:
http://flesler.blogspot.ca/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html

Comment: Oh my...this may be exactly what I'm looking for.  Going to play around with this a bit and check out it's power.  Thank you good sir.

Comment: You are very welcome, if this is what you are looking for, please do not forget to let me know!

Comment: This is so close Ghillied, and maybe I'm just missing something...I see I can flush the contents of the XML writer out to a string and it works beautifully, formats exactly how I need it...Is there a way that I can provide a link on my page that the user can right-click, save as, the xml code produced?  I need a way to get the code onto the local desktop.

Comment: You could use this: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 
function WriteFile()
{

var fh = fopen("c:\\MyFile.txt", 3); // Open the file for writing

if(fh!=-1) // If the file has been successfully opened
{
    var str = "Some text goes here...";
    fwrite(fh, str); // Write the string to a file
    fclose(fh); // Close the file 
}

}

WriteFile();

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

to write the file on the server with a specific filename and just put a href link on your webpage/webapp so people can right-click and save the file as whatever you want them.
Note: Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Despite the way this hosed your formatting I get that, ha.  Since this is a web page that will be just run locally (not hosted on a server but stored in a local html file) could I just use that WriteFile() function to write to an XML file in the same directory as the local HTML file that they are manipulating it with?  If so that makes all of this rather easy and I'll be ecstatic!

Comment: I'm going to mess around with it and see what I can do.

Comment: Alright. That may not be the right answer still, so I'll keep an eye out for you !

Comment: Hmm...apparently fopen is PHP?  I'm not going to be able to use any PHP unfortunately.  Trying to get this to work without installing any additional software on the client's machine.  Again, I don't know if this is even possible at this point...but I'm hoping.

Comment: My bad, sir, totally forgot about that.You could take a look at this then: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <script language="javascript"> function WriteToFile() { var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Test.txt", true); s.WriteLine('Hello'); s.Close(); } </script> Juste create some loops to read the xml stored inside a variable or however you set your code. And change the fileext.

Comment: This...a thousand times this.  Despite the fact that this IE only and runs only in quarks mode, it is going to do exactly what I need it to do.  Thank you good sir!

Comment: Have a nice day, it was a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of background, but I'm not entirely sure of of the technical side to your question. One part seems related to HTML5 local storage - there is a [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) that might help here but I haven't tried this myself.

The other part of your question is about modifying XML on the browser client. Possibly the best solution for this would be to use XSLT, a language designed to transform XML.

[Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/doc/about/intro.xml) is an XSLT 2.0 processor for the browser. Being a JavaScript application it has the JavaScript interoperability you would need to integrate with local storage on the client when needed. I understand that you're at an early stage, but if you're looking into feasible options then Saxon-CE should probably be on your list.

Comment: Yea I'll take a look at these.  I know I provided a lot of background.  I was trying to make the scenario easy to understand.  What the problem comes down to is that I need a way to either form a new XML file that the user can manually save, or form a new XML file that can be saved to a specified location on the user's file system.  I have limited space to work with installing this functionality and this should all work locally on the machine, i.e. no server/client relation.  I hope that helps clarify.  I'm going to go read your suggestions now.

Comment: @Benhamine Yes, background is good. So, regarding the file writing, this blog article may help: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/  - Also, I understand the need for no client/server relation that's why a browser-hosted XSLT processor (uncompressed size about 1MB) with JavaScript interoperability could be an option for your XML processing.

Comment: Ok, I've read through these and I knew about XSLT, for some reason I misread your post and was thinking you said it would help with the file writing portion.  I was confused there for a good portion of time, ha.  As for the Filesystem API, this really looks useful and would probably do the trick.  I may end up using it.  My only concern is that Chrome is the only browser that currently fully supports it.  I'd prefer this to run in IE, as it's the standard installed browser (...dreaded IE...).  I'm going to keep rooting around but this may do the trick.  Thanks good sir!

Comment: It also appears that the FileSystem API doesn't like running on local machines :(

"For security reasons, browsers do not allow you to run your app from file://. In fact, many of the powerful storage APIs (such as File System, BlobBuilder, and FileReader) throw errors if you run the app locally from file://."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File_API/File_System_API/FileError

Comment: Perhaps you should consider hosting IE inside a .NET application (using the WebBrowser control) then? With this you can access the local file system from the browser with the same privileges as .NET. From JavaScript you can then call something like: windows.external.myinterface.store(xmlString); which will call a .NET method.